# Easy question on equlibrium solutions of $\frac{dy}{dt}= (3-y)(y-t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Hi guys I was reading through a ODE book and stumbled on this

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= (3-y)(y-t)$$

Where to book claims that $y=3$ is a equilibrium solution but $y=t$ is not. Can someone explain. How I understood it was that the values that make $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$ are the equilibrium solutions and $t$ clearly does that, so I am confused.

Comment: If $y-t=0$ then $\frac{dy}{dt}=1$..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$y=t$ is not even a solution. If you substitute that in, you get the equation $1=0$.

An equilibrium solutions is a solution where $y$ is constant as time $t$ changes. So $y=c$ for some number $c$, and consequently $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$. So this equation would become $$0=(3-c)(c-t)$$ and that equation is a *functional* equation, true for all values of $t$, not just some special values. As an algebraic equation, the only solutions are $c=3$ and $c=t$. But the latter is not possibly true for a constant $c$ and all values of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y=t$ was an equilibrium solution. It certainly satisfies that $(y-t) = 0$ and thus that $(3-y)(y-t)=0$. However, it would have the problem that $y'(t) = 1$, not zero...